# java https keep alive

Tags: java, http, https

Нужно у одного хоста быстро запрашивать веб странички. Использовал java.net.URL для отправки запросов, но каждый раз создается новое подключение, что довольно долго. Есть какие то классы, где можно установить соединение и изменять путь запрашиваемого документа?